# Keep it json on Scala

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Hi guys i am reading on scala a Json like this below in a dataframe:

```
{
  "key": {
    "code": "1"
  },
  
  "data": {
    "array": [
      {
        "type": "a",
        "bool": true
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

Then i need to generate a dataframe with columns:
key_code and data_array when data_array colums has the value (as String):

```
[
      {
        "type": "a",
        "bool": true
      }
]
```

The key_code column is ok but for data_array i am having a problem... i try to code like this:

```
dataFrame
            .withColumn(
              "data_array",
              explode(col("data.array"))
            )
           .withColumn("DATA_ARRAY", col("data_array").cast("String"))
```

But i am getting ["a",true] and not the expected result that i mentioned, someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`to_json`** function from **`Spark-2.2`**

```
df.show()
//+-------------+---+
//|         data|key|
//+-------------+---+
//|[[[true, a]]]|[1]|
//+-------------+---+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

df.withColumn("key_code",col("key.code")).
withColumn("da",explode(col("data.array"))).
withColumn("DATA_ARRAY",to_json(array(col("da")))).
drop("data","key","da").
show(false)

//or using selectExpr
df.selectExpr("key.code","explode(data.array)").
selectExpr("code","to_json(array(col)) as data_array").show(false)

//+--------+--------------------------+
//|key_code|DATA_ARRAY                |
//+--------+--------------------------+
//|1       |[{"bool":true,"type":"a"}]|
//+--------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help fellow, but i am sorry, i forgot to mention, my program is running in spark 1.6.3